# Are Exterminatus weapons ever used against ships?

Tags: warhammer-40k

It seems like if a cyclonic torpedo can destroy a planet, it could also destroy any ship.  Same idea with virus bombs.  If the virus from a virus bomb can wipe out all life on a planet in short order, it seems like it could also do that to a ship.  Getting it on the target is simple; load a boarding pod with a virus bomb instead of marines.

So do they do this kind of thing, or no?  If not, why not?

Comment: This might be better for world building.  But I think some of the marines are in environmentally controllable suits, not mention all the various air locks.  That seems like you could control the spread of a virus in that manner. Reading wiki: I guess it penetrates environmental suits, but I it still seems like you could seal off or jettison part of the ship if necessary.

Comment: The virus bomb isn't foolproof; some of the Astartes on Istvan III survived.  The Cyclonic Torpedo (at least certain variants) requires an atmosphere to sustain the chain reaction.  Massive orbital bombardment (the most common form of Exterminatus) requires a large fleet of ships and a target that isn't firing back at you.  None of these seems suitable as a fleet combat weapon.

Comment: i'm pretty sure The Flight of the Eisenstein has virus bombs going off inside a ship, and sealed bulkheads are enough to contain them

Answer (score 4):

**Wildly Inefficient**

The only instance I can think of is when HDMS Lord Solar Macharius uses cyclonic torpedoes (of which they only have a few, specially issued for the task) to destroy a particularly nasty ork infestation in an asteroid belt.  They're fired at the ork Roks (basically asteroids with engines/guns) to great effect.  I'd point out though that at the point in the Gothic war where this happens Battlefleet Gothic is on the ropes and desperate to clear its supply lines, and everyone involved acknowledges that while effective it's a desperation move.

The Imperium's technology is vast, but their production methods are archaic.  The more impressive the technology, the more complex the production.  That's not just the actual science behind making a plasma gun or whatever, it's the mysticism surrounding it.  This is a culture that requires a trained cult to do things like press the 'On" button for fire-fighting equipment (Battlefleet Gothic main rulebook).  The creation of Exterminatus-grade weaponry is a closely guarded secret by those few tech-priests which posses the knowledge to manufacture them. They take AGES to produce (BFG sources indicate a single NORMAL Imperial torpedo takes a decade to manufacture) and are exceedingly rare.  To the point where an Inquisitor Lord with all their power and trappings might have access to a single cyclonic torpedo or virus bomb, but probably not both at once.  Likewise Imperial Navy Battlefleets and Space Marine Chapters might own a handful of such weapons with resupply being hard or even impossible for some makes. (for example, if it's Phosphex based they don't make those anymore.)

So we're talking about weapons that may be centuries old, and may or may not be replaceable.  They're designed primarily for a single function, to destroy a planet.  Using such a weapon against a ship would probably be seen as a criminal waste of resources at best, and tech-heresy at worst.

Now there are things I would classify as sub-exterminatus that could do the trick.  Massed Nova cannons or Bombardment cannon fire could purge a world.  Heck, battleships are frequently described as heaving broadsides that could "wreck continents" and their primary mission is blowing up other ships.  But the one-shot=planetkill type weapons aren't something an admiral wanting to keep his position (to say nothing of his head) would use without some overriding need or specific order.

Comment: This is a nice answer but you could improve it by [edit]ing in quotes/evidence to back up your points! Especially on the first point of where these are used.

Comment: I'm just thinking some ships might be worth as much or more than a planet.  Like maybe Abbadon the Despoiler's flagship.

Answer (score 2):

This would probably fall under or be very close to Tech-Heresy:

> Even among the unusually open-minded Explorators of the Adeptus Mechanicus, there are subjects which must be avoided at all cost to remain true to the dictates of the Machine God. A Heretek enthusiastically violates all such strictures, exploring xenos technology, archeotech from the Dark Age of Technology, and dabbling in all facets of technology related to the manipulation of the Warp. He may even be bold enough to develop entirely new technologies, combining components in forbidden manners to produce the ultimate tech-heresy for many in the Cult Mechanicus---innovation. He may go as far as sharing the tools of his trade and the secrets of its ways with those who have not been trained in the mysteries of the Machine God. A Heretek actively seeks out new technology and continuously experiments with new techniques in ways that were once forbidden. He no longer believes that any information, experiment, or device can be ignored. Rather, he deliberately focuses on those technologies that the Mechanicus' teachings once taught him to avoid, with a particular interest in developing Warp-based technologies.
>
> From the [Calixpedia Article on Tech-Heresy](https://calixipedia.fandom.com/wiki/Tech-Heresy)

The Imperium, and specially the Adeptus Mechanicus, is not keen of developping new ways to solve an issue as today's society does. They have their approved ways, in the best case from an STC. Combining technology into something new or use something in a way it was not intended / approved for will very probably get you court-marshalled.

You probalby wouldn't even be able to do execute your plan as the Adepts of the Mechanicus would never agree to help you with this.

Answer (score 1):

Virus bombs would be an extremely inefficient ship-to-ship weapon. Even if the virus was successfully introduced into the target ship, its spread would be halted by the ship's internal structure. As described in *Rogue Trader* and *Battlefleet Gothic*, Imperial ships are designed with compartmentalized purge systems as a last-ditch firefighting mechanism - there can't be any fire if the compartment's been vented into space. (Well, technically there can, but much less fire.) This would also handily deprive the virus of targets and eventually destroy it, while the airtight bulkheads themselves would halt its spread. All in all, it would be easier and cheaper to just use conventional torpedoes.